# Regarding properties of non-transitive dice

Tags: probability

First I'm not a mathematician so please ask for clarifications.

Is it required condition for the set of non-transitive dice to have numbers that are not common amongst themselves? So for example following cannot be non-transitive dice because dice B and C have 3 in common (of course they are non-transitive also because they don't satisfy basic definition):

A: 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 6

B: 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3

C: 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

As an aside, are there any rules of thumb to check by looking at a set of n six-sided dice and tell that they cannot be non-transitive?

Comment: A link to the [definition of non-transitive dice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice) could help.

Comment: The Wikipedia page doesn't answer the question though...

Comment: The condition that the numbers be different is not part of the definition.

Comment: Miwin's dice have sides in common.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miwins_dice

Comment: Thanks all. Take it the post was a non-question. However, is there a quick way to tell if a set of six-sided dice cannot be non-transitive? I've writing an algo and brute force is taking too long to find out. I had a look at math.ku.edu/~jschweig/dice.pdf but it has a precondition that numbers on a die's face shouldn't repeat on other faces of that die or any other die. I want to allow the numbers on a die's face to repeat. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370183/quick-way-to-tell-if-a-set-of-dice-is-not-non-transitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exemple of non-transitive dices with a common value (`1`) is:

```
1 1 3 3 3 3
1 1 1 3 4 4
1 2 2 2 3 4
```